eFLL - Arduino using two fuzzy systems in the same program
I'm trying to write a program but I encounter some issues.
I try to define 2 fuzzy controllers in the same set-up of a program. Both share an input and have one more  input  different from each other. This is the initialization of the input/output. The second controller, fuzzydist output returns 0.00. I should not. I am using the eFLL library Did anybody do that? How I am supposed do to it?
Fuzzy *fuzzy = new Fuzzy();
Fuzzy *fuzzydist = new Fuzzy();
void setup() {
FuzzyInput *velocity = new FuzzyInput(1);
  fuzzy->addFuzzyInput(velocity);
  fuzzydist-> addFuzzyInput(velocity);
FuzzyInput *weather = new FuzzyInput(2);
  fuzzy->addFuzzyInput(weather);
FuzzyInput *road = new FuzzyInput(3);
  fuzzydist->addFuzzyInput(road);
FuzzyOutput *reaction = new FuzzyOutput(1);
   fuzzy->addFuzzyOutput(reaction);
FuzzyOutput *reaction = new FuzzyOutput(1);
   fuzzy->addFuzzyOutput(reaction);
}
void loop (){
  fuzzy->setInput(1, velocity); 
  fuzzy->setInput(2, road); 
  fuzzy->fuzzify();
  float tau1 = fuzzy->defuzzify(1);

  fuzzydist->setInput(1, velocity); 
  fuzzydist->setInput(3, road); 
  fuzzydist->fuzzify();
  float a = fuzzydist->defuzzify(2);
}

I am expecting that the second controller should return a float <10, >0.
I tried to write the program in which the FLL won't share the input but it dosen't work either, it returns 0.00 also.
